When I update the data after submitting the data, the data changes order and is not sequential according to the ID
the data changes order and is not sequential according to the ID
this my UserController:
// Edit Data User
export const editUser = async (
  id: number,
  formData: FormData,
  newPassword?: string
) => {
  const validasiUser = newPassword
    ? UserPasswordSchema.safeParse(Object.fromEntries(formData.entries()))
    : UserSchema.safeParse(Object.fromEntries(formData.entries()));
  if (!validasiUser.success) {
    return {
      error: validasiUser.error.flatten().fieldErrors,
    };
  }

 try {
    const { username, email, userRole } = validasiUser.data;
    const updateData: any = {
      username,
      email,
      userRole,
    };

    if (newPassword) {
      const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(newPassword, 8);
      updateData.password = hashedPassword;
    }

    const updateUser = await prisma.user.update({
      where: { id },
      data: updateData,
    });
    console.log("berhasil mengupdate", updateData);

    return { success: true, data: updateUser };
  } catch (error) {
    return { error: "Gagal meng Update data" };
  }
};

this my edit form user:
"use client";
import React, { useRef, useCallback, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { Button, Modal, Table } from "react-daisyui";
import { editUser } from "../../../controller/UserController";
import { getUsersByID } from "../../../lib/user";
import { BiSolidEdit } from "react-icons/bi";

const EditUser = ({ onSuccess, id }: { onSuccess: () => void; id: number }) => {
  const ref = useRef<HTMLDialogElement>(null);
  const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = useState(false);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false);
  const [formData, setFormData] = useState({
    id: id,
    username: "",
    email: "",
    userRole: "",
    password: "",
    confirmPassword: "",
  });

  const handleShow = useCallback(() => {
    setIsModalOpen(true);
  }, []);

  const handleClose = useCallback(() => {
    setIsModalOpen(false);
  }, []);

  const handleUpdate = async (event: React.FormEvent<HTMLFormElement>) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("Form Data:", formData);

    try {
      setIsLoading(true);
      const UserData = new FormData();
      UserData.append("id", formData.id.toString());
      UserData.append("username", formData.username);
      UserData.append("email", formData.email);
      UserData.append("userRole", formData.userRole);
      UserData.append("password", formData.password);
      UserData.append("confirmPassword", formData.confirmPassword);

      const result = await editUser(id, UserData);
      console.log("Result:", result);
      setTimeout(() => {
        setIsModalOpen(false);
        setIsLoading(false);
        onSuccess();
      }, 1000);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error occurred while submitting form", error);
    }
  };

  const handleInputChange = useCallback(
    (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
      const { name, value } = event.target;
      setFormData((prevFormData) => ({
        ...prevFormData,
        [name]: value,
      }));
    },
    []
  );

  const handleSelectChange = useCallback(
    (event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
      const { name, value } = event.target;
      setFormData((prevFormData) => ({
        ...prevFormData,
        [name]: value,
      }));
    },
    []
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    if (id) {
      const fetchAdminData = async () => {
        try {
          const adminData = await getUsersByID(id);
          if (adminData) {
            setFormData({
              id: adminData.id,
              username: adminData.username,
              email: adminData.email,
              userRole: adminData.userRole,
              password: "",
              confirmPassword: "",
            });
          }
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error fetching user data:", error);
        }
      };
  
      fetchAdminData();
    }
  }, [id]);
  

  return (
    <div className="font-sans">
      <Button
        onClick={handleShow}
        className="rounded-lg bg-cyan-500 text-white btn btn-sm hover:bg-cyan-600 border-stroke hover:border-stroke translate-x-0 pl-2">
        <BiSolidEdit size={20} />
      </Button>
      <Modal
        ref={ref}
        open={isModalOpen}
        className="bg-white dark:bg-gray-900 text-black dark:text-white border-stroke">
        <Modal.Header className="font-bold text-center">
          {id ? "Edit" : "Tambah"} Admin
        </Modal.Header>
        <Modal.Body>
          <form onSubmit={handleUpdate}>
            <div className="my-4">
              <div>
                <label className="mb-3 mt-4 block text-sm font-bold text-black dark:text-white">
                  Username :
                </label>
                <input
                  type="text"
                  name="username"
                  placeholder="Masukkan Username..."
                  defaultValue={formData.username}
                  onChange={handleInputChange}
                  className="w-full rounded-lg border-[1.5px] border-stroke bg-transparent px-5 py-3 text-black outline-none transition focus:border-primary active:border-primary disabled:cursor-default disabled:bg-whiter dark:border-form-strokedark dark:bg-form-input dark:text-white dark:focus:border-primary"
                />
              </div>
              <div>
                <label className="mb-3 mt-4 block text-sm font-bold text-black dark:text-white">
                  Email :
                </label>
                <input
                  type="email"
                  name="email"
                  placeholder="Masukkan Email..."
                  value={formData.email}
                  onChange={handleInputChange}
                  className="w-full rounded-lg border-[1.5px] border-stroke bg-transparent px-5 py-3 text-black outline-none transition focus:border-primary active:border-primary disabled:cursor-default disabled:bg-whiter dark:border-form-strokedark dark:bg-form-input dark:text-white dark:focus:border-primary"
                />
              </div>
              <div>
                <label className="mb-3 mt-4 block text-sm font-bold text-black dark:text-white">
                  Role :
                </label>
                <select
                  name="userRole"
                  value={formData.userRole}
                  onChange={handleSelectChange}
                  className="w-full rounded-lg border-[1.5px] border-stroke bg-transparent px-5 py-3 text-black outline-none transition focus:border-primary active:border-primary disabled:cursor-default disabled:bg-whiter dark:border-form-strokedark dark:bg-form-input dark:text-white dark:focus:border-primary">
                  <option value="">-- Pilih Role Akun --</option>
                  <option value="Admin">Admin</option>
                  <option value="Petugas">Petugas</option>
                  <option value="Siswa">Siswa</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <div>
                <label className="mb-3 mt-4 block text-sm font-bold text-black dark:text-white">
                  Sandi :
                </label>
                <input
                  type="password"
                  name="password"
                  placeholder="Masukkan Sandi"
                  value={formData.password}
                  onChange={handleInputChange}
                  className="w-full rounded-lg border-[1.5px] border-stroke bg-transparent px-5 py-3 text-black outline-none transition focus:border-primary active:border-primary disabled:cursor-default disabled:bg-whiter dark:border-form-strokedark dark:bg-form-input dark:text-white dark:focus:border-primary"
                />
              </div>
            </div>
            <div>
              <label className="mb-3 mt-4 block text-sm font-bold text-black dark:text-white">
                Masukkan Ulang Sandi :
              </label>
              <input
                type="password"
                name="confirmPassword"
                placeholder="Masukkan Ulang Kata Sandi..."
                value={formData.confirmPassword}
                onChange={handleInputChange}
                className="w-full rounded-lg border-[1.5px] border-stroke bg-transparent px-5 py-3 text-black outline-none transition focus:border-primary active:border-primary disabled:cursor-default disabled:bg-whiter dark:border-form-strokedark dark:bg-form-input dark:text-white dark:focus:border-primary"
              />
            </div>
            <div className="m-2 mt-4 flex justify-end">
              <Button
                onClick={handleClose}
                type="button"
                className="text-white bg-rose-600 hover:bg-rose-700 border-stroke hover:border-strokedark">
                Close
              </Button>
              <Button
                type="submit"
                className="text-white bg-blue-600 hover:bg-blue-800 border-stroke hover:border-strokedark relative"
                disabled={isLoading}
                style={{
                  backgroundColor: "#2563EB",
                  color: "white",
                  marginLeft: "10px",
                }}>
                {isLoading ? (
                  <>
                    <span className="loading loading-spinner text-white"></span>
                    Menyimpan
                  </>
                ) : (
                  "Simpan"
                )}
              </Button>
            </div>
          </form>
        </Modal.Body>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
};

export default EditUser;

this my table User:
"use client";
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import CreateUser from "../AccountModal/create";
import { getUsers } from "../../../lib/user";
import { EditButton, DeleteButton } from "../Button/button";
import EditUsers from "../AccountModal/edit";

interface Users {
  id: number;
  username: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
  userRole: string;
}

const User: React.FC = () => {
  const [users, setUsers] = useState<Users[]>([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);

  const fetchData = async () => {
    try {
      setLoading(true);
      const userData: Users[] = await getUsers();
      const sortedUserData = userData.sort((a, b) => a.id - b.id);
      setUsers(sortedUserData);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error fetching users:", error);
    } finally {
      setLoading(false); // Memindahkan penundaan ke sini
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="rounded-lg border border-stroke bg-white px-5 pb-2.5 pt-6 shadow-default dark:border-strokedark dark:bg-boxdark sm:px-7.5 xl:pb-1 font-sans">
      <div className="flex justify-between mb-4">
        <h4 className="mb-6 text-xl font-semibold text-black dark:text-white">
          Table User
        </h4>
        <CreateUser onSuccess={fetchData} />
      </div>
      <div className="overflow-x-auto">
        <table className="border-collapse border border-stroke dark:border-strokedark w-full text-black dark:text-white">
          <thead>
            <tr className="bg-gray-200 dark:bg-gray-800 font-bold">
              <th className="border border-stroke px-4 py-4.5 font-medium">
                No
              </th>
              <th className="border border-stroke px-4 py-4.5 font-medium">
                Username
              </th>
              <th className="hidden border border-stroke px-4 py-4.5 font-medium sm:table-cell">
                Email
              </th>
              <th className="border border-stroke px-4 py-4.5 font-medium">
                Action
              </th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr>
              {loading && (
                <td colSpan={4} className="text-center py-10">
                  <span className="loading loading-spinner loading-lg text-primary"></span>
                </td>
              )}
            </tr>
            {!loading &&
              users.map((user: Users, index: number) => (
                <tr
                  key={index}
                  className="bg-gray-200 dark:bg-gray-800 text-center">
                  <td className="border border-stroke px-4 py-4.5 items-center">
                    {index + 1}
                  </td>
                  <td className="border border-stroke px-4 py-4.5">
                    {user.username}
                  </td>
                  <td className="hidden border border-stroke px-4 py-4.5 sm:table-cell">
                    {user.email}
                  </td>
                  <td className="border border-stroke px-4 py-4.5 flex justify-center space-x-2">
                    <EditUsers id={user.id} onSuccess={fetchData} />
                    <DeleteButton id={user.id} onSuccess={fetchData} />
                  </td>
                </tr>
              ))}
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default User;

this my lib user.ts:
"use server";
import { prisma } from "./prisma";

interface Users {
  id: number;
  username: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
  userRole: string;
}
export const getUsers = async () => {
  try {
    const users = await prisma.user.findMany();
    return users;
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error("Failed to fetch user data");
  }
};
export const getUsersByID = async (id: number): Promise<Users | null> => {
  try {
    const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
      where: { id },
    });
    return user || null;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Failed to fetch user data:", error);
    throw new Error("Failed to fetch user data");
  }
};
"use server";
import { prisma } from "./prisma";

interface Users {
  id: number;
  username: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
  userRole: string;
}
export const getUsers = async () => {
  try {
    const users = await prisma.user.findMany();
    return users;
  } catch (error) {
    throw new Error("Failed to fetch user data");
  }
};
export const getUsersByID = async (id: number): Promise<Users | null> => {
  try {
    const user = await prisma.user.findUnique({
      where: { id },
    });
    return user || null;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Failed to fetch user data:", error);
    throw new Error("Failed to fetch user data");
  }
};

this my prisma schema:
model User {
  id          Int       @id @default(autoincrement())
  email       String    @unique
  username    String
  userRole       String
  password    String
  createdAt   DateTime  @default(now())
  updatedAt   DateTime  @updatedAt  
}

I hope that when the data is updated there will be no changes in the order because i want data not change after edit(update) data.

use key={user.id} for the tr tag in the loop, this is better so that react can render the elements in the list better since a fixed value like the user.id is constant and the index is not

This is the answer. React documentation (see the "Pitfall" section here) advises against using index as key for this very reason.

OK thank you, but when the data is updated the IDs are not sequential and don't stay, which is what I want is that only the data that is updated is changed, not the position of the data.
